# Colorizing and highlighting text in HTML for R Shiny

Tags: html, r, colors, shiny, highlight

I ran a bunch of NLP algorithms on a big corpus and I want to explore my results. In other words, I want to be able to format text in HTML based on features that my models have extracted in order to view them in a Shiny web application like this :
[image]

As I don't know anything about html, can you direct my research by telling me which ways I should consider? Do some R packages exist to do this kind of tasks? Are Shiny functions sufficient? If so, which functions?

Comment: I would suggest uploading an example because it's quite a general question. A helpful lead might be wrapping words with the `span()` function, and adding the `style` argument, like that: `span("your_string", style = "color: red;")`

Comment: Thanks a lot yanirmor, this is what I needed to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this answers the question exactly but it may be relevant:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(spacyr)
require(shiny)

tempDir <- tempfile()
dir.create(tempDir)
htmlFile <- file.path(tempDir, "index.html")
viewer <- getOption("viewer")

s = spacy_parse(sample(stringr::sentences, 25), dependency=T, nounphrase=T) %>% as_tibble()
print(s)

# A tibble: 224 x 11
   doc_id sentence_id token_id token lemma pos   head_token_id dep_rel entity nounphrase
   <chr>        <int>    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     
 1 text1            1        1 Brea… brea… VERB              1 ROOT    ""     ""        
 2 text1            1        2 deep  deep  ADJ               1 acomp   ""     ""        
 3 text1            1        3 and   and   CCONJ             1 cc      ""     ""        
 4 text1            1        4 smell smell VERB              1 conj    ""     ""        
 5 text1            1        5 the   the   DET               7 det     ""     "beg"     
 6 text1            1        6 piny  piny  ADJ               7 amod    ""     "mid"     
 7 text1            1        7 air   air   NOUN              4 dobj    ""     "end_root"
 8 text1            1        8 .     .     PUNCT             1 punct   ""     ""        
 9 text10           1        1 Fill  fill  VERB              1 ROOT    ""     ""        
10 text10           1        2 the   the   DET               4 det     ""     "beg"     
# … with 214 more rows, and 1 more variable: whitespace <lgl>

cols = sample(rainbow(15))
pos_types = s %>% count(pos, sort=T) %>% print() %>% .[['pos']]

sink(htmlFile)
cat('<h4>')
  for(i in 1:nrow(s)){
    col = cols[match(s$pos[i], pos_types)]
    cat(as.character(span(s$token[i], style=glue::glue('color:{col}'), 
                          title = paste(s$pos[i], s$dep_rel[i]))))
    cat(' ')
  }
cat('</h4>')
sink()

viewer(htmlFile)
```

[image]